# Hatcher's 4.1.15: Not even understanding the question!

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Good people, I'm having problems even understanding some aspects of Hatcher's Ex. 4.1.15, which makes it rather difficult to actually solve it.

The question looks like this:

[image]

My questions are as follows:

1. What does Hatcher mean when he writes "Show that every map $f: S^n \rightarrow S^n$ is homotopic to **a multiple of the identity map**"? (own emphasis.) *Multiple* in what sense? What is the "scalar" here?
2. What does Hatcher mean in (b) when he writes "collapses the complement of a small ball about $q$ to the **basepoint**"? (own emphasis.) What is the *basepoint* of the map in this context?

Look forward to you sorting this out for me. No doubt this is fairly trivial.

Comment: scalar is an integer. $n[id] = [id] + \cdots + [id]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1: In earlier portions of the book, you have learned that $\pi_n(S^n)$ is an abelian group (assuming that $n \ge 2$). Hatcher is taking advantage of that fact in part (a), which allows him to use some shortcuts of terminology.

One can re-expand that shortcut by writing

> ... every map $f : S^n \to S^n$ is homotopic to **a map that represents the same element in $\pi_n(S^n)$ as** a multiple of **the element represented by** the identity map.

And, of course, in the context of an abelian group, a "multiple" of an element means an integer multiple; here one uses the fact that abelian groups are $\mathbb Z$-modules. For the case of a positive integer $n$ and the identity map $id$, this is written out explicitly in the comment of @КряжевАрсений:
$$n[id] = \underbrace{[id] + [id] +... + [id]}_{\text{$n$ times}}
$$

Question 2: In a context where one is working with a topological space and its homotopy group $\pi_n(X)$, such as part (b), the notation $\pi_n(X)$ is itself a shortcut for an expanded notation $\pi_n(X,b)$, where one implicitly assumes that a base point $b \in X$ has been chosen. So the "base point" referred to in part (b) is that implicitly chosen basepoint.

Comment: Well, Mr Mosher, this hasn't been the first time you've helped me out, and I hope I can rely on you again in the future. Thanks a bunch! :)